# How to give access to my angular application for redirecting to a particular URL redirected by node js server using res.redirect()

Tags: node.js, angular, express

The following is my code in angular and node js. In which I am trying to use a post request and the response once it is success means it should redirect to particular url. But unfortunately my angular application is unable to handle that response.

In controller.js:

```
sandbox.saveSandboxOrder(sandboxDetails, order_id).then(ordersave_success = > {
        if (ordersave_success) {
            response.redirect(200, ordersave_success.redirectUrl);
        } else {
            response.send('Failed'));
        }
});
```

In angular:

component.ts:

```
pay() {
    var obj = {
        "apiKey": "",
        "memberId": ""
    }
    this.merchantService.authenticateUser(obj).subscribe(res = > {
        if (res) {} else {
            console.log('no data')
        }
    })
}
```

In service.ts:

```
authenticateUser(data) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/authenticateUser', data);
}
```

All the implementation is right but it cannot able to handle redirection url giving by my node server.In console it is showing as:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/authenticateUser", ok: false, …}
    error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "OK. Redirecting to https://www.google.com"}
    headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
    message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/authenticateUser"
    name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    url: "http://localhost:8080/authenticateUser"
```

Comment: Can you confirm the http status for the api call? Does it come back with 302 Redirect or with 200 ok? (Make the same api call using postman to your backend and share the response)

Comment: Its 200 and the postman response is like 200 ok redirecting to https://www.google.com  ==>something like this i presently kept that address to redirect

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the redirection that is happening is returning 200 as you specify: `response.redirect(200, ordersave_success.redirectUrl);`. This makes the angular app decide that the response has been successfully received and not follow the redirection. Redirection should be done using 3xx HTTP Status code. I'm assuming you're using express to enable you to do response.redirect, which according to their [Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) will default to HTTP Status 302 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302).
Therefore remove the 200 enforced status code, or select a more explicit and meaningful HTTP status dependning on your actual use-case from the 3xx range.